# How to check if file exist in specified url in type script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, blob

Hi I am working in react application. I am retrieving set of files from azure blob and downloading files. I am able to do this. I am checking if file exist or not before downloading.

```
const containerURL: ContainerURL = new ContainerURL( url,                 
                           StorageURL.newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential()));             
                           const listBlobsResponse = await containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment(Aborter.none, marker);      
                           const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL,reporthPath);
   // here want to check if specified file exist or not
   const link = document.createElement('a');           
                         link.href = blockBlobURL.url;     
                        window.open(link.href, "_blank")
```

can someone help me how can I check if blob exist or not. any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `specified file` what is the specified file? does the url specify the specified file? if the sepcified file doesn't exist, wouldn't you get an error condition when trying to create the blob?

Comment: specified file is nothing but blobkbloburl.url. if file is not found then i am getting error from azure storage itself The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:b6579557-101e-00d7-23bd-8c6d71000000 Time:2020-09-17T06:38:45.0351525Z but i want to test before server error comes

Comment: I wouldn't check in advance whether the file exists, I'd just start the read operation and deal with failure. For one thing, there's always the (presumably small) chance that the file could exist (or not exist) as of when you do the existence check but then no longer exist (or be created) when you would have started the read operation. In general, "check for file then try to read it" is a bit of an antipattern.

Comment: @MrPerfect - *"but i want to test before server error comes"* Why?

Comment: You can try with httpclient and check the response

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API you're using, but from the description, isn't `listBlobFlatSegment` already a bit of a "does it exist" check? It says it *"listBlobFlatSegment returns a single segment of blobs starting from the specified Marker."* Why would it list blobs that don't exist? :-) Anyway, don't think I can help; good luck with it!

Comment: Only thing is if file doesnt exist I want to show custome message but now I am getting back error message directly from server

Comment: Just wrap it with the error handler

Comment: Hi Ahfa in the above code in which line I can wrap error handler?